# add class to the element inside template clone (Google Script)

Tags: javascript, html, queryselector

I make a copy of this template:

```
<template id="inputTemplate">
  <div class="input-group input-line mb-1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control issues-input" size="40" placeholder="Descripcion..." required>
    <div class="input-group-append" id="button-addon4">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-input"  type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary remove-input"  type="button"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

and I want to add a class to all elements within this copy that have ".input-line" with this script

```
  function addFirstAcHidIssue(){
            var template = document.getElementById("inputTemplate")
            var issues = document.getElementById("ac-hid-issues")
            var copy = template.content.cloneNode(true)
            issues.appendChild(copy)
            issues.querySelector(".input-line").classList.add("aceite-hidraulico-issues")
            
       }
```

It appends a child but no luck with the adding a class to .input-line

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Using your code, I created this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/g2ztds3m/) that shows your code works. I gave `aceite-hidraulico-issues` a backgorund of red to show that it was working.

Comment: Your code works with me as well. Can you show us the HTML where "ac-hid-issues" is included?

Comment: that was the problem in this section, I found it finally: it adds class to the first cloneNode. but if I keep calling this functon and adding clones - they are created already without mentioned class... any ideas?